# Can jQuery intellisense also be installed / used in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-designer

There are some references on how to install intellisense for jQuery in VS2008SP1, is it also possible for SharePoint Designer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment so posting my own answer.. Charles and Jaap are right.. SPD wasn't designed to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Highly unlikely in my opinion, I don't think SPD is - nor it's meant to be - a very extensible application.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Designer was never intended to be used for custom code of any sort, even though you can obviously inject client side code into a page using it.

So I would suspect that Microsoft have deliberately not invested time and effort in developing that side of the product.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 has Jquery intellisense.
Hope this helps